# PHP. Display content of SQL table based on selection chosen in dropdown box

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Sorry if this has been asked and answered but I have looked and can't see it anywhere. Yes I am a nooby.

I have a DB with 3 tables: flour, filler and others.

What I would like to do is have a dropdown List. So, if user chooses flour from the Drop Down box it will display flour table. If the user chooses filler then filler table be displayed.

Hope this is clear. I hope you can help. Thanks in advance.

```
<Form id="form1" name="form1" method="get" >
Supplies of
<select name=filler action="flour.php">
<option value="1" selected>flour</option>
<option value="2">filler</option>
<option value="3">others</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>


<?php
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1251");
@mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
@mysql_select_db('krendel');
@mysql_query('SET NAMES cp1251'); 
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `flour` ") or die(mysql_error());
$res2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `filler` ") or die(mysql_error());
$res3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `addit` ") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: 'Action' needs to be on the 'form' tag, not the 'select' tag.

Comment: <Form id="form1" name="form1" action="flour.php" method="get" >
</Form>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the action to the form, not select element. So you'd have

```
<form method="get" action="flour.php">
```

and

In your form processing script (flour.php), you could so something like this:

```
switch($_GET['filler'])
{
    case '1':
       $table = 'flour';
       break;
    case '2':
       $table = 'filler';
       break;
    case '3':
    default:
       $table = 'addit';

}

$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$table}");
```

If all tables have the same structure, consider combining the tables, and adding a type column (varchar containing either flour, filler, or addit for simplicity). 
you could then write the query like this (still using the $table variable name to work with the code above.

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE type='{$table}'");
```

Using mysql_query, and concatenating variables into the SQL is not good practice now - have a look at PDO and parameterised queries as you learn more.

Some quick and dirty display code:

```
<?php 
$results = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res, MYSQL_ASSOC)) { ?>
    $results[] = $row;
} 
?>

<table>
    <?php foreach($results as $result) { ?>
        <td><?php echo $result['column_name'] ?></td>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```

This should get you started - as I said above, it's quick and dirty. You'll be able to improve upon this as you get more knowledge (properly separating out the HTML from PHP, for example - it's really worthwhile reading up on MVC amongst other patterns). 
Just don't use this code on a production system!

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The page that is going to display the table needs to check the `$_GET['filler']` and see what the value is.  Since you are using `$_GET` and a drop box, you should have a white list something like: `$filler_white_list = array('flower', 'filler', 'other');`

Check to see if the value of `$_GET['filler']` is in the `$filler_white_list` array.  If the `$_GET['filler']` value is valid, then make your query:

```
$res = mysqli_query('SELECT * FROM '.$_GET['filler'].';') or die(mysqli_error());
```

Then loop through the result set to print out to the page:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){  
    //get the columns by using $row['column_name']
    //decide how you want to format 
}
```

Things to note: I used `mysqli` instead of `mysql`, because the `mysql` is deprecated (no longer supported), The `SELECT` statement uses an `*`, but it is better to list out the names of the column since it is faster. It is not a good idea to use the the values of the drop box as the name of you tables in the database.  The less information you reveal about your database, the better.  Of course, if this is not for a production DB, then it doesn't matter.  But, I think it is always best to think about security even when you're just practicing. Also, I put the `$_GET['filler']` in the middle of the `SELECT` statement because the table's names are the same as the drop box.

Comment: I just realized that the values that are being sent over are 1, 2 and 3 and not 'flour', 'filler' and 'others', so Panoctopus' switch statement is better and works as a white list.